# How to determine the root character

Tags: python-3.x

The title was vague so I will fill you in on what I am saying:

I want to in Python be able to determine the root character of a character, like this:

ǻ + [backspace] = å = a
meaning that the root character of ǻ is a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `unicodedata.normalize` function for this:

```
from unicodedata import normalize

letter = 'ǻ'
letter = normalize('NFD', letter)
print(letter[0]) # a
```

`unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)` translates each the string into its decomposed form.

An easier and more reliable method, however, is to use the [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.1) module:

```
from unidecode import unidecode

print(unidecode('ǻ')) # a
```

Comment: Thank You, I was not sure this was possible

Comment: If this answer solved your question, click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer, so people know it's solved.